# Is there a Glossary of Terms for the Federal Elections Commission API?

Tags: government, metadata, openfec

Maybe I missed it on the FEC API site (https://api.open.fec.gov/developers/) but does anyone know if there's a glossary which defines all of the elements in the models? For example, if you scroll down to /Financial/ and open up `/committee/{committee_id}/reports/` you some obvious items like: `all_loans_received_period (integer, optional)`,

Which I imagine is all the loans taken by the committee in that period; and some mysterious ones, like: `fed_candidate_committee_contributions_period`

Are these contributions to the committee *from* Federal candidates? *To* Federal candidates?

I have a bunch of clarifying questions on the listed items but before I start just asking everything I was wondering if these terms are defined somewhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the original fec site is still main reference while the other is in beta. search for metadata, data dictionary, or glossary. here's a few, but i'm sure there are others. you should add the ones you find here:

http://www.fec.gov/finance/disclosure/metadata/DataDictionaryWEBK.shtml#search=data%20dictionary
Electioneering Communications metadata
http://www.fec.gov/finance/disclosure/metadata/DataDictionaryECdownload.shtml
Committee report by report metadata
http://www.fec.gov/finance/disclosure/metadata/MetadataforCommitteeReportbyReportSummary.shtml#search=metadata
Transaction Type Codes metadata
http://www.fec.gov/finance/disclosure/metadata/DataDictionaryTransactionTypeCodes.shtml#search=metadata

More Terms
http://www.fec.gov/pages/brochures/indexp.shtml